# How can I get rid of the message "kvm: disabled by BIOS"?

Tags: kernel, kvm-virtualization

I'm getting a message:

```
kvm:disabled by bios
```

after upgrading my kernel to 3.8.x. I've never installed the KVM package. Neither I can **enable virtualization** from my BIOS, because of a BIOS bug. I just want to get rid of this weird message. Tried removing any kernel module using *modprobe* but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. This question specifically asks how to suppress the message given that the BIOS arbitrarily disables virtualisation, and is focused on *keeping virtualisation disabled*. The other question is (implicitly) asking *how to enable virtualisation*, with the error message being a symptom of the problem, rather than the problem itself. So although I agree that the questions are related, I don't think they're the same. In fact, they might even be considered opposites.

Comment: It's not a dupe but it is a [question seeking a workaround for a bug](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5305/12864) and so should be closed as off-topic instead.

Comment: It's a BIOS bug, not an Ubuntu bug, for which a workaround is being sought. I don't think this fits with the spirit of the off-topicness of bugs, since a BIOS bug doesn't generally belong on Launchpad either, really.

Comment: @RobieBasak we do not care who's fault is the bug, it's a bug and needs to be fixed by the one that develops them. Is simple. If the bug-tracker isn't LP then look for it, bugs are bugs and hence off-topic independently what part of the software/hardware/firmware has it.

Comment: It's not even a bug. Many BIOSes intentionally ship without any way to enable VT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-kvm.conf`:
(For example, you can use gedit `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-kvm.conf` or nano `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-kvm.conf`)

Put in it the following three lines:

```
blacklist kvm
blacklist kvm_intel
blacklist kvm_amd
```

I'm not sure if this will work for you, because I don't have a suitable system also disabled by BIOS. But this is a reasonable way of disabling KVM on Debian or Ubuntu, so you should try and see if it also works to disable your message.

Comment: Worked for me on OpenSuse Leap 42.2. Just run mkinitrd after editing /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf

Answer (score 20):

What worked for me:

1) Turn on the computer and press f2 to see the setup (BIOS) when you see a screen with black background.

2) Go to "Configuration" tab.

3) Select the option "Intel Virtual Technology" and enable it by pressing F5 or F6.

4) Press F10 to save and exit. When a prompt message appears asking you to confirm this action, select yes.

5) Your computer will turn off for 10 seconds. Then, it will boot and load your OS without showing that error.

Comment: actually *enabling* it seems like a better solution (rather than just hiding the error message)!

Comment: @hayd: Thanks for your comment. As you said, it is a different way for approaching the same problem.

Comment: KVM requires that the virtual machine host's processor has virtualization support (named VT-x for Intel processors and AMD-V for AMD processors). You can check whether your processor supports hardware virtualization with the following command: $ egrep --color=auto 'vmx|svm|0xc0f' /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: This is certainly better than hiding the error. I had the same problem with my Arch installation and enabling Intel VT in the BIOS resolved this error.

Comment: Thanks. This working for me. Lenovo ideapad 15ibd

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you might want to see if `KVM` is loaded in the kernel. To do this, run something like this:

```
lsmod | grep kvm
```

If you do get any answer from that, you may want to stop kvm from running. To do that, this will help:

```
modprobe -r kvm
```

Remember to follow for any other kvm module. In my case, there is also a `kvm_intel` module, so I also have to run

```
modprobe -r kvm_intel
```

To stop `kvm` from being enabled at boot time you have to find the file located at `/etc/modules` and modify it so that KVM doesn't launch at boot time. After you modify your `/etc/modules` file restart your computer and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove kvm

```
sudo apt-get purge qemu-kvm
```

or ignore that message, it is not hurting anything.

Perhaps there is a bios update available ?

Comment: This breaks vmware

Comment: "ignore the message" is not an answer to the question (the OP _doesn't_ want to keep ignoring it).

Comment: @isomorphismes which is why the first option - remove KVM. the kvm kernel module conflicts with the vmware module. You might be able to manually load/unload the kernel modules, I am not sure with vmware.